Meaning of negative frequency in nonlinear susceptibility?
When I am learning the nonlinear optics, for cases like difference frequency generation and optical rectification, the second order susceptibility tensor can take the form $\chi(0;\omega,-\omega)$. How am I suppose to understand the $-\omega$ here and its physical meaning?

This notation is a matter of convention. The positive and negative sign mean incoming and outgoing fields. The first argument, before the semicolon, is the frequency of the polarization that is induced. The negative sign indicates that the material looses energy by radiating at $\omega$, while the positive sign indicates an incoming field that provides energy to the material.
The sum of all arguments should be zero due to energy conservation. You get to this convention by considering all the Delta Dirac functions that occur when you calculate the nonlinear polarization in frequency space and execute the integrals over the Delta functions.
An explanation of the convention is given here  Nonlinear Optics Lecture Notes by Mark Kuzyk, 2010, in Section "2.3.3 A Note on Notation and Energy Conservation".
As a shorthand it basically tells you how the terms look like that contribute to your polarization. If your total inducing field is a sum of two monochromatic waves, you can deduce the following for the second order contribution,
$$
P_i^{(2)}(\omega) = k \sum_{\omega_\alpha,{\omega_\beta}} \chi_{ijk}^{(2)}(\omega_\alpha,\omega_\beta ) E_j^{\omega_{\alpha}}E_j^{\omega_{\beta}}\delta(\omega - \omega_\alpha - \omega_\beta)
$$
where $\alpha,\beta\in \{\omega', \omega'', -\omega', -\omega''\}$, assuming an total incoming field of the form
$$
E_j(\omega) = \delta(\omega-\omega')E_j^{\omega'} + \delta(\omega+\omega')E_j^{-\omega'} + \delta(\omega-\omega'') E_j^{\omega''} + \delta(\omega+\omega'')E_j^{-\omega''}
$$
which is the Fourier transform of a field that consists of two monochromatic waves, one at frequency $\omega'$ and the second at $\omega''$,
$$
 E_i(t)= (e^{-i\omega't}E_j^{\omega'} + e^{i\omega't}E_j^{-\omega'} + e^{-i\omega''t} E_j^{\omega''} + e^{i\omega''t}E_j^{-\omega''})
$$
$k$ is just a scalar constant with all numerical factors, physical constants, etc. And $i,j,k \in \{x,y,z\}$
Terms in this sum are easily deduced from the notation, for example
$$\chi_{ijk}(-\omega; \omega',\omega'')\rightarrow \chi_{ijk}(\omega',\omega'')E_j^{\omega'}E_k^{\omega ''} \delta(\omega -\omega'-\omega'')$$
I didn't check numerical prefactors and constants that may vary depending on your Fourier Transform pairs and units systems, but I think that covers the gist of it. Definitions also vary often so its always a good idea to do the calculations once yourself with your own definitions to check whether you can identify everything correctly. Nonlinear optics literature is horrible when it comes to conventions and small details in my experience, so its always recommended to double check equations.
